# Error compiling Java file with special characters in class name

Tags: java, javac

I am encountering an issue compiling a source file with a special character in the class name.  The class file compiles fine in the Eclipse IDE, but not from javac.  I believe I need to leverage the `-encoding` flag, but haven't hit the right setting yet.  I would appreciate any pointers:

**File Name:**  DeptView和SDO.java

**Java Source:**

```
public interface DeptView\u548cSDO {

   public int getDeptno();

   public void setDeptno(int value);

}
```

**Error Message:**

Running `javac *.java` results in the following error message:

```
javac: file not found: DeptView?SDO.java
```

**UPDATE**

- I am currently trying the compile at a Windows XP command prompt
- Ultimately this compile will need to be part of an ant build, an run on different operating systems
- I work on the tool that is producing this generated source file.

Comment: Bleugh, why are there special characters in the class name in the first place? I take it this isn't your doing ;)

Comment: Can you not simply rename the class and source file? Seems odd to me to use non-ASCII characters in a class name.

Comment: It looks like he's using source code from another team, or something. For compatibility reasons, it'd be a pain to rename.

Comment: @Chris Dennett and @Bernard - The source file is auto generated.  Renaming is not an option for this particular use case.

Comment: Which OS with which settings is used? Which process/program writes the filename into the directory?

Comment: @Michael Knoietzka - I have updated the question with additional information.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One solution is to list the file name of each compilation unit in a separate file, say `files`, and pass `@files` as a command-line argument to `javac`. Otherwise, you will have to set the locale of your shell, so that it is using the correct character encoding.

Comment: +1: I suspect it is not a problem with the `javac` program itself, but rather with the shell.

Comment: +1 - At this point I believe the problem is due to the character encoding of the Windows command window I am using as I am able to compile this in Eclipse and with javac on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `-encoding UTF8` or `-encoding UTF16LE` (Little Endian) or `-encoding UTF16BE` (big endian)? (The usage of LE or BE depends on the system you are using -- Windows is LE from what I remember.)

Comment: Thanks for the input. I just tried those encodings, but I'm still getting the same error.