# java compiler enconding issue with non-ascii characters in class file name

Tags: maven, encoding, jenkins, javac, xmlbeans

I've got a problem similar to ([Error compiling Java file with special characters in class name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5993979/error-compiling-java-file-with-special-characters-in-class-name))

the scenario is as follows: i'm using jenkins to build a project that uses xmlbeans-maven-plugin:2.3.3 to generate and compile java classes from xsd.
My xsd file has got some types with special characters in the name, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?
...    
<xs:complexType name="tipoAttività">
            <xs:simpleContent>
                <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                    <xs:attribute name="Cod" type="xs:string"/>
                </xs:extension>
            </xs:simpleContent>
        </xs:complexType>
```

when I build on my local windows7 machine, everything is Ok, when I commit on svn and build on jenkins (on a linux machine - ubuntu12.04), or if I try to build on a development unix machine, I get the error:

```
class TipoAttivit?Impl is public, should be declared in a file named TipoAttivit?Impl.java
```

I tryed to compile manually passing -enconding option to the compiler, with this result:

```
$ javac -encoding ISO-8859-1 TipoAttivit\?Impl.java
TipoAttivit?Impl.java:14: error: class TipoAttivitàImpl is public, should be declared in a file named TipoAttivitàImpl.java
public class TipoAttivit\u00e0Impl extends org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.JavaStringHolderEx implements it.honyvem.hvtola.hv2La.TipoAttivit\u00e0
```

**Please note that the compiler prints the *file* name with the question mark AND prints the *class* name correctly with the "à" character**.

I tryed to specify ISO-8859-1 encoding everywhere, but I can't get rid of the error.
I suspect that the problem is in the way xmlbeans plugin generate the source files, but I didn't find any options to specify the encoding.

Here's my pom:

```
<properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>ISO-8859-1</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <finalName>xsd_honyvem_common</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <encoding>ISO-8859-1</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                  <encoding>ISO-8859-1</encoding>
                </configuration>
              </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>xmlbeans-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.3</version>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>xmlbeans</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources/xsd</schemaDirectory>
                            <memoryInitialSize>32m</memoryInitialSize>
                            <memoryMaximumSize>64m</memoryMaximumSize>
                            <verbose>true</verbose>
                            <xmlConfigs>
                                <xmlConfig implementation="java.io.File">
                                    src/main/resources/xsd/common.xsdconfig
                                </xmlConfig>
                            </xmlConfigs>
                            <noJavac>true</noJavac>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
                        <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
                        <version>2.2.0</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Can someone help me?

EDIT:
If I manually amend the file name like this:

```
$ mv TipoAttivit\?Impl.java TipoAttivitàImpl.java
```

The compiler seems to work fine:

```
    $ javac -encoding ISO-8859-1 TipoAttivitàImpl.java
TipoAttivitàImpl.java:14: error: package org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values does not exist
```

TipoAttivitàImpl.java:14: error: package org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values does not exist
So definitely the problem is in the way xmlbeans generates the source files.

Comment: If I manually modify the file name like this: