# Compiling error while using non-ASCII characters in class name

Tags: java, intellij-idea, non-ascii-characters

Assignment requires that I use non-ASCII characters when naming main class:

public class SõnadeAnalüüs {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

//code

I use IntelliJ. When trying to run I get 
Error: Could not find or load main class SonadeAnaluus
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: SonadeAnaluus.

If I replace ä and ü with a/u, everything works.

I have changed encoding to UTF-8 in every possible place.

Is there anything else I can try?

EDIT: How I use IntelliJ: 
1. Start new Java Class, write code, run it using Run MyClass.main() (Ctrl+Shift+F10). 
Like I said, when not using umlauts, everything works.

EDIT2: I am quite new to programming and this community, so I apologize in advance if I do something wrong.

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried not doing that? I mean why not use ASCII.

Comment: Is the file name on disk binary identical to the class name?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5993979/error-compiling-java-file-with-special-characters-in-class-name?noredirect=1&lq=1) question might address the same issue.

Comment: It seems like a command-line/launcher issue. IntelliJ users might know right away but everyone should be able to help you if you [edit] your question with more details about how you are starting the program.

Comment: Please see http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/2013/03/use-the-utf-8-luke-file-encodings-in-intellij-idea/. Try adding `-Dfile.encoding=UTF8` in Help | Edit Custom VM Options and in Compiler VM options in IntelliJ IDEA. Restart, rebuild. If the issue persists, please share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Thorbjørn I'm not sure I understand correctly your question but my class name and .java file name are exactly same.

Comment: @AleksMosk Even when taking locale encodings into consideration?  The byte sequence of the name might be different on disk and inside the jVM

Comment: Try launching via your shell/console like `java SõnadeAnalüüs` (or whatever it takes). The error suggests that something is doing the equivalent of `java SonadeAnaluus`.

Comment: @TomBlodget I don't know which of the two did it, but I got it working now.

 First I changed regional settings to my native language. 

Second when testing my files on cmd I used javac -encoding UTF-8 SõnadeAnalüüs.java after which successful compiling is done both on command line and IntelliJ.

Comment: Regional settings (similar technical concepts: culture, locale, collation) are important because they allow software to adjust to user preferences for number, date, and currency formatting and text sorting. It's usually not good when software also uses them to adapt to character encodings—at least not in this century. IntelliJ probably has a setting to get out of this trap.

Comment: @AleksMosk The problem seem to be that the operating system and the JVM disagrees on how the unicode characters in your class name should be converted to the bytes in the filename on disk.  So when the byte code file is written it is not the correct name.  This is a prime example on why non-ASCII characters should only be used sparingly in Java sources (yet!)